# Does SQL Azure Cache rows that have just been created?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure that does an insert of a row like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_add_test  
    @CreatedBy NVARCHAR (128),       
    @TestId    INT      
AS 
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    INSERT INTO dbo.Test (
       CreatedDate,
       Title,
       ParentTestId,        
    )
    SELECT 
       @CreatedDate
       Title,
       @TestId
    FROM    Test
    WHERE   TestId = @TestId;

    SELECT * from Test
    WHERE   TestId = @TestId
    AND    CreatedDate = @CreatedDate;
END
```

When inserted a new identity value will be generated for the primary key. As soon as the insert is completed I then do a select from that table.

Can someone tell me if there is another way I can do this? The reason I do a second select is that I need to get a value for the new TestId which is an identity column.

I am not familiar with the way SQL Server caches data. Does it cache recently used rows in the same way as Oracle does or will it go to the disk to get the row it just inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, the right way to do this is with the `OUTPUT` clause.  The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

As far as I know, SQL Azure supports the `OUTPUT` clause.

As for your question, when a database commits as page (that is, when the `insert` is completed), the page often remains in memory.  Typically, the "commit" is a log operation, so the data page remains in memory.  An immediate access to the page should be fast, in the sense that it doesn't require a disk access.  But the `OUTPUT` clause is the right approach in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into how I can use this. Actually I noticed that it seems my SP does not output anything. I am wondering if this is because I have no commit between the insert and the select.